# HPC: Autospawn new parallel task when memory is full

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

In my HPC application, i sometimes end up filling all the memory through dynamic allocation and loose performance. I am using MPI-fortran. Is there a programming model/environment where the environment could spawn new process when i am close to fill the memory? I can imagine how such a model would require me to explicitly specify how problem will be partitioned. Has any such thing been implemented yet?

Comment: You can monitor your memory allocation (by counting it before malloc/after free or by `getrusage()`. MPI-2 allows you to spawn new MPI processes (`MPI_Spawn`). The `free` utility from the command line can report total memory size and swap size.

Comment: Good idea. But I was interested to know if there was a programming model supporting this.

Comment: What is the "programming model"?

Comment: By programming model, i mean programming environment and its abstraction of the machine. For example, MPI programming model assumes a set of interconnected processing elements which communicate via message passing (even though N number of processes might be executed on a single processor).

Comment: MPI's dynamic process management is poorly suited for scaling out single jobs. It's primary use is to implement pipelines and coarse-grained task parallelism. There are some programming models built around Apache Hadoop that implement automatic scaling but their applicability depends heavily on what kind of problem you are solving.

Comment: Thanks, i'll see if it is suitable for my problem.